# decompose the permutation $\sigma$ in cycle notation into an object

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

A permutation of a set  is a bijection (one-to-one and onto) : → .

As an object a permutation $\sigma$ looks like this:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
    2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 5\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

They can also be written in terms of cycle notation which looks like this for the above permutation:

$(1,2,3),(4), and (5,6)$

I want to take the following permutation in cycle form and convert it into its form as an object.

$(1,3)(1,2)(4,5)$

It is the duplication of the $1'$s in two separate orbits that are throwing me off. I have been taught to go from right to left

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply $(13)(12)(45)=((13)((12))(45)=(123)(45)$.  From there the object form is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow how the cycles act on elements. For instance (working right to left), we have for $(1\;2)(1\;3)\;(2\;3)$
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 1
    \end{matrix}
$$
For instance, tracking the action of this product acts on 2. First, it sends 2 to 3 then it sends that 3 to 1 then it sends that 1 to 2. Therefore, it fixes 2. Follow the action of elements similarly. [Note again, you may have been taught to compose left to right, rather than my right to left. It depends on the convention you are learning.]